# Рекурсия для меню

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть такая рекурсия на меню

```
function menu($id)
{
    $tree_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE parent=$id AND checked=1");
    while ($menu_tree = mysql_fetch_assoc($tree_res)) {
        $res    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE parent='$menu_tree[id]'");
        $check2 = mysql_fetch_row($res);
        if ($check2 == true) {
            echo "<li><a href='/category.php?id=$menu_tree[id]'>$menu_tree[name]</a>";
            echo "<ul>";
            menu($menu_tree['id']);
            echo "</ul></li>";
        } else {
            echo "<li><a href='/catalog.php?id=$menu_tree[id]'>$menu_tree[name]</a>";
            echo "<ul>";
            menu($menu_tree['id']);
            echo "</ul></li>";
        }
    }
    return;
}
menu(0);
```

Если у родителя есть дети, то выводит и их, все работает хорошо, но в исходном коде в меню вписываются пустые теги `<ul></ul>`, как от них избавиться? Меню обычное на ul li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот есть у вас следующий код -

```
echo "<ul>";
menu($menu_tree['id']);
echo "</ul></li>";
```

В нем как раз видно, что тэги, обрамляющие список выводятся до и после вызова функции , отрисовывающей меню. Я бы рекомендовал, если это необходимо, внести их вывод внутрь самой функции, и перед выводом (цикл while ($menu_tree = mysql_fetch_assoc($tree_res))) проверить, вернул ли запрос хоть какие-то данные. Если их нет, значит, подменю пустое и тэги списка нам не нужны.

Comment: А поможете реализовать =)?

Comment: Условие будет выглядеть так:
if(mysql_num_rows($tree_res)>0)
  $isactive = true;
else
  $isactive = false;

Соответственно, перед и после while поставьте if($isactive) echo (открывающий или закрывающий тэг)

Comment: Не помогло, но скорей всего я может допустил ошибку. Легче просто что бы скопировали мой код, и поставили бы правило туда куда следует

Comment: все спасибо помогло :)

Comment: Замечательно. Удачи в дальнейшей работе.